# How to Deserialize a JSON when I have nested object?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

JSON response string send by client:

```
{  "{\"user_id\":\"\",\"school_id\":\"1\",\"user_name\":\"pfirstname1@example.com\",\"firstname\":\"pfirstname1\",\"surname\":\"psurname1\",\"type\":\"P\",\"phoneno\":\"1446863\",\"mobileno\":\"3614632\",\"address\":\"mehdipatnam\",\"relation\":\"Father\",\"date_created\":\"\",\"student_dto\":": {    "{\"student_id\":0,\"user_id\":0,\"firstname\":\"sfirstname1\",\"surname\":\"ssurname1\",\"rollno\":1,\"class_id\":\"2\",\"school_id\":\"1\",\"address\":\"mehdipatnam\",\"remarks\":\"\",\"date_created\":\"\"}]}": ""  }}
```

Then to deserialize this I'm doing this step:

```
dynamic data = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(response.ToString(), typeof(object));
```

Then when I look in to the debugger I can see:

```
[0] {[{"user_dto":{"user_id":"","school_id":"1","user_name":"pfirstname1@example.com","firstname":"pfirstname1","surname":"psurname1","type":"P","phoneno":"1446863","mobileno":"3614632","address":"mehdipatnam","relation":"Father","date_created":"","student_dto":, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]]}  System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,object>
```

But how do I access the values?

Comment: So, that response string is very much not well formed JSON.

Comment: My response string is constructed in javascript

Comment: The 2 bojects here are  students_dto[childrencount] = {
                student_id: 0,
                user_id: 0,
                firstname: sfname,
                surname: ssname,
                rollno: 1,
                class_id: classid,
                school_id: schoolid,
                address: my_address,
                remarks: "",
                date_created: "",
                sex: sex
            } and

Comment: the the user_dto var users_dto = {
                user_id: 1,
                school_id: schoolid,
                user_name: my_email,
                password: "",
                firstname: pfname,
                surname: psname,
                type: "P",
                phoneno: my_phone,
                mobileno: my_mobile,
                address: my_address,
                relation: relation_t,
                remarks: "",
                date_created: "",
                student_dto: students_dto
            };

Answer (score 0):

I'm going into this assuming that the mess you posted as JSON should actually be the following after all the `\"` and erroneous quotes are removed.

```
{
    "user_id":"",
    "school_id":"1",
    "user_name":"pfirstname1@example.com",
    "firstname":"pfirstname1",
    "surname":"psurname1",
    "type":"P",
    "phoneno":"1446863",
    "mobileno":"3614632",
    "address":"mehdipatnam",
    "relation":"Father",
    "date_created":"",
    "student_dto":
    {
        "student_id":0,
        "user_id":0,
        "firstname":"sfirstname1",
        "surname":"ssurname1",
        "rollno":1,
        "class_id":"2",
        "school_id":"1",
        "address":"mehdipatnam",
        "remarks":"",
        "date_created":""
    }
}
```

If that's the case, then json2csharp.com gives the following as the classes to deserialize into:

```
public class StudentDto
{
    public int student_id { get; set; }
    public int user_id { get; set; }
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string surname { get; set; }
    public int rollno { get; set; }
    public string class_id { get; set; }
    public string school_id { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string remarks { get; set; }
    public string date_created { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string user_id { get; set; }
    public string school_id { get; set; }
    public string user_name { get; set; }
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string surname { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string phoneno { get; set; }
    public string mobileno { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string relation { get; set; }
    public string date_created { get; set; }
    public StudentDto student_dto { get; set; }
}
```

Now you should be able to deserialize directly into that type.

```
new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<RootObject>(response.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks, Craig. I have discovered the bug it was at the clients end. your answer is perfect.